# Cascading Encryption with Multiple Keys

Tags: aes, encryption

AES is symmetric encryption, so if I encrypt using key1, I can always decrypt using key1. If I encrypt using key2, I can always decrypt using key2.

I want to apply this encryption multiple times with multiple keys to strengthen it. I want to encrypt my cipher first using key1, then encrypt the result using key2, and then the result using key3, and so on. As illustrated below:

- cipher -> enc with key1 -> enc with key2 -> enc with key3 -> result

In order to decrypt the result, I have to decrypt in reverse:

- result -> dec with key3 -> dec with key2 -> dec with key1 -> cipher

My question is, does there exist a key that represents the product of key1, key2 and key3, so that it will decrypt the result in one pass? Meaning, can an attacker simply find a key4 that would short-circuit my scheme?

- result -> dec with key4 -> cipher

Comment: I recall from my networks security course, that encrypting a file with several keys doesn't strenghten it that much. Can't elabroate more then that since that's all I can remember :) If you want higher protection you're better of using aes with 256bit key

Comment: If you want to strengthen it, then simply use your key as input of PBKDF2 or bcrypt, with sufficient salt and iteration count. Don't ever directly use a password or string as a key.

Comment: I believe this is asking if AES is a group under composition with different keys. This is better asked in [crypto](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I am wondering whether it would be a good way to slow down brute force attack as the attacker will have to decrypt multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no such thing for AES, nor is it likely that there will be. This would only be possible if the AES algorithm would be seriously flawed.

This does not mean you cannot find a concrete sample where such a key might exists (still very unlikely), but there is no process to extract a combined key out of multiple others.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know this thread is quite old, but any reference to back up this assertion would be very useful.

Answer (score 1):

CryptoLib (https://github.com/IcyApril/CryptoLib) supports cascading (layered) encryption using different encryption ciphers; it uses 1 key, but that undergoes PBKDF2 hashing at each encryption level (with SOHA alternations between Whirlpool and SHA512). This will protect you in case one cipher is broken, the others still stand in it's place, in order to call it, you simply do this (replacing path/to with where you put CryptoLib):

```
<?php
  require_once('path/to/cryptolib.php');
  $encryptedString = CryptoLib::encryptData("Test string.", "password");
  $decryptedString = CryptoLib::decryptData($encryptedString, 'password');
?>
```

To directly answer the initial question, building on this: In order to use three separate keys (in a cascading fashion) with CryptoLib you can just call the encrypt function three times.

```
<?php
  require_once('path/to/cryptolib.php');
  $encryptedString = CryptoLib::encryptData("Test string.", "password1");
  $encryptedString = CryptoLib::encryptData($encryptedString, "password2");
  $encryptedString = CryptoLib::encryptData($encryptedString, "password3");
?>
```

And to decrypt the string, call the decrypt function 3 times in reverse:

```
<?php
  require_once('path/to/cryptolib.php');
  $decryptedString = CryptoLib::decryptData($encryptedString, "password3");
  $decryptedString = CryptoLib::decryptData($decryptedString, "password2");
  $decryptedString = CryptoLib::decryptData($decryptedString, "password1");
?>
```

CryptoLib source is on GitHub at: https://cryptolib.ju.je/ and documentation site is https://cryptolib.ju.je.

Answer (score 0):

Due to [meet-in-the-middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meet-in-the-middle_attack), the security of triple encryption is O(2^256) for AES-128.

This attack was found when 3-DES designed.

AES, actually, designed with different key size for future development of attacks and possible hardware improvements except Quantum Computing. AES by designs has 128, 192 and 256 bits. AES-256 will be faster than 3-AES-128 with the same security.